# how to unsubscribing from live data android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have fragment `ProductsFragment` which display list of products in a recycler view.

when an item is clicked on the recycler view  it takes me to `AddProductFragment` where it displays the product details of the item clicked. this I have done using `SharedProductViewModel` which has a selected mutable live data

The issue I am facing is on `ProductsFragment` I have an floating action button which I use to navigate to `AddProductFragment` to add a new product. but It displays the previously clicked product details from the list

SharedProductViewModel

```
class SharedProductViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Product>()

    fun select(product: Product) {
        selected.value = product
    }
}
```

ProductsFragment - when item is clicked

```
private val model: SharedProductViewModel by activityViewModels()

   private fun listItemClicked(product: Product) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected name is ${product.name}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        model.select(product)
        navController.navigate(R.id.addProductFragment)
    }
```

AddProductFragment - which shows the previously clicked product details when clicked on add new product icon

Note: observer gets triggered always whether clicked on item or a plus button to add new product

```
  private val model: SharedProductViewModel by activityViewModels()

   model.selected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Product> { item ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "item clicked and received" + item.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            addProductViewModel.updateProductDetails(item)
        })
```

I do not want it to show the previously clicked product details when add new product is clicked.

how can i do this please

thanks
R

Comment: Add a bundle to the fragment transaction to tell the next fragment whether it should show a new product or the selected one in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Selected and New Product are inherently two different models, so I suggest you keep two different `LiveData` objects; one for each, like so:

```
val selectedProduct = MutableLiveData<Product>()
```

&

```
val newProduct = MutableLiveData<Product>()
```

Just remember to reset `newProduct` to `null` each time you've successfully added a new product. This will make sure you don't have old data showing up.

Comment: Hi I do not have a new model for new product

Comment: You do not need a new type just a new object of type Product. How you create that object is to you and depends on your code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bundle to the fragment transaction to tell the next fragment whether it should show a new product or the selected one in the view model.

When instantiating the Fragment, add a bundle to it before you pass it to the transaction to show it:

```
val fragment = AddProductFragment().apply {
    arguments = bundleOf("isNewProduct" to true)
}
```

Then in the Fragment, you can make a property that reads the value. Use this Boolean to determine whether you observe the current product live data or not.

```
private val isNewProduct: Boolean get() = arguments?.getBoolean("isNewProduct") ?: false
```

Comment: If you're using the Navigation component, you can do this using navigation arguments instead.